# How do I save excel file in read-only mode using phpExcel module

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am trying to get users to save/download my excel file in read-only mode (apache on windows server, all users downloading are using windows).

So far, I have looked around for a good solution and have tried everything suggested but nothing seems to be working.

I tried adding following lines:

```
$objPHPExcel->getSecurity()->setLockWindows(true);
$objPHPExcel->getSecurity()->setLockStructure(true);
```

but still it is saving in an editable mode. Am I missing something here?

I would prefer a solution where above mentioned goal is achieved by using phpexcel but the use of core php is also acceptable.

Something that requires a modification to phpexcel core class won't be acceptable as there's a whole bunch of applications developed by other developers in our organisation who assume core class to be untouched.

Comment: I believe this is not possible, as read/write access is usually set at OS level by an admin, etc. If it is a file download, the user can just take off the read-only anyways.

Comment: Yes, the read-only can be taken off but it's meant to be in read-only mode by default. I am not sure about "it's not possible" part though. Can someone confirm please?

Comment: If you're talking about the way MS Excel automatically puts any documents downloaded from the internet in "read only" node, then this isn't something configurable in the Excel file itself, but a setting in MS Excel

Answer (score 2):

I did not found any way without set password.

```
// Set password for readonly activesheet
$objPHPExcel->getSecurity()->setLockWindows(true);
$objPHPExcel->getSecurity()->setLockStructure(true);
$objPHPExcel->getSecurity()->setWorkbookPassword("password");

// Set password for readonly data
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setSheet(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setPassword("password");
```

Answer (score 0):

from the docs:

> Document security allows you to set a password on a complete spreadsheet, allowing changes to be made only when that password is entered.

The example they give is as follows:

```
$objPHPExcel->getSecurity()->setLockWindows(true);
$objPHPExcel->getSecurity()->setLockStructure(true);
$objPHPExcel->getSecurity()->setWorkbookPassword("PHPExcel");
```

it looks like you're missing the password.

Comment: I don't want to set a password. I want to have the doc in read-only mode so that user has to 'enable editing' before modifying any piece of information in the document.

Comment: are you talking about the `enable editing` that pops up in office excel? if so, that is a feature of the program. I don't think it is something you can force. it's there for the user's protection (so he or she doesn't accidently edit a document), and it is something that they can turn off so they never see it.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me from editing the value of cells and formatting them.

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setSort(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setInsertRows(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setFormatCells(true);
```